# Inserting values to different tables based on variables

Tags: php, mysql

```
     $username = $_POST['uid'];
      $email = $_POST['mail'];
      $password = $_POST['pwd'];
      $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];
      $date = $_POST['date2'];
      $stream = $_POST['relationship'];

            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers, relationship) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Family1 (username, application_filed, relationship) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO Family2 (username, application_filed, relationship) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
            mysqli_query($sql1, $conn);
            mysqli_query($sql2, $conn);
            mysqli_query($sql3, $conn);

       $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
              header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
              exit();
            }
                    else {

              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $date, $stream);
              $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
              if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              ($username==$_SESSION['uid'] and $stream =='nursing');
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            }

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
              header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
              exit();
            }
                    else {

              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $date, $stream);
              $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
              if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              ($username==$_SESSION['uid'] and $stream =='doctoral');
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            }

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql1)) {
              header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
              exit();
            }

     if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql1)) {
              header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
              exit();
            }
            else {
              $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $username, $email, hashedPwd,$stream);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
              header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
              exit();



/////////////New Code////////////////
  $username = $_POST['uid'];
  $email = $_POST['mail'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];
  $date = $_POST['date2'];
  $stream = $_POST['relationship'];

        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers, relationship) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Family1 (username, application_filed, relationship) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO Family2 (username, application_filed, relationship) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
        } else if ($username==$_SESSION['uid'] && $stream =='nursing') {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $date, $stream);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
        }
        else if ($username==$_SESSION['uid'] && $stream =='doctoral') {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $date, $stream);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql1)) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
        }
        else {

           $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd, $stream);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
          exit();

        }
```

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I have this code. They idea I had behind it is to insert values into different tables depending on variables being passed.

So when user fills out a form and selects $stream="nursing" I want results to go to table 'users' and 'Family1', but not 'Family2' table. and if user selects $stream='doctoral' results should go to table 'users' and  'Family2', and not go to 'Family1'

But with my query I get results go to both table and also users table. And there is no restriction to what users selects, variable $stream being passed no matter what it is.

Is this the wrong way to go here? Did I completely mess up the logic?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: yes you need first to prepare teh sql statement see https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Why do you have two "family" tables? One should be sufficient. Additionally, try and `prepare`/`bind`/`execute` on one query at a time to avoid jumbling them up.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the `mysqli_query()` calls at the top will try to run the queries and will fail, since it has no understanding of the `?` placeholders and you have the `$conn` and `$sqlX` variables the wrong way around.

But aside from that, let me fix the indentation for you so you can see what's actually happening for one of your statements:

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $date, $stream);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        ($username==$_SESSION['uid'] and $stream =='nursing');

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Do you see what's happening here?

`$sql2` is an `INSERT` query. If you were able to prepare that statement you try to get the result *before the query is even executed*. If you manage to retrieve a row of data from that result (*which you can't* since an INSERT query does not return any records), you then do a check on `$username` and `$stream` that has no effect. The call to execute the prepared statement is executed regardless of whether or not you managed to get anything from `$result`.

All your statements have the same problems, so I'll only fix this one.

Here's what I changed:

- The whole `$result` step seemed unnecessary, so I removed it.
- I replaced `and` with `&&` because of my personal preference. There was once a reason why it became my preference, but I forget. It's mostly for consistency between programming languages, since many languages use `&&` and only a few use `and`.
- Since there's no point in binding params to a statement you're not planning to execute, I moved that into the if-statement.
- Since I now ended up with an `else { if { ... } }` construction, I simplified that down to an `else if { ... }` for cleaner code.

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
} else if ($username==$_SESSION['uid'] && $stream =='nursing') {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $date, $stream);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Now, the query `$sql2` is only executed if the `$username` matches the current `uid` from the session and the user selected the `nursing` stream.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense and I really appreciate the knowledge share. I did modify my script as you suggested, but I dont see any output except for table 'users' only being updated. The query goes through but no results are being inserted to tables Family1 or Family2 I will edit my code as well but it is now identical to yours

Comment: Then the `if` statements aren't passing. Is that logic correct? Does the value of `$username` match what's in `$_SESSION['uid']`? Is `$stream` either `'nursing'` or `'doctoral'`?

Comment: I updated my original post with new code. So nothing is being populated right now except for username table. Doesnt matter what I select which stream. But yes I only want to pass the selected stream to one table and username should go to other one.

Comment: Hey rickdenhan thanks again for your help. I think issue could be something with      $username = $_POST['uid']; ?? that I have defined at the top and than also using it in IF statement? Either way I removed $username from the equation and only left else if ($stream =='nursing')  and it does the job for me, It works. I dont know why I was thinking about using username also..